# Производительность сайта по сдаче тестирования

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Делаю сайт по прохождению тестирования. Пользователь заходит на сайт выбирает категорию тестов и начинает прохождение. В каждой категории до ста с лишним вопросов. Как лучше в плане производительности?:

1. Выбирать все тесты и ложить их в некое хранилище типа сессий (или какого-нибудь redis) после выбора категории (т.е. перед началом самого тестирования) и затем уже выдавать каждый тест (вопрос) оттуда или же
2. в первом варианте нет смысла и можно вытаскивать каждый тест из БД (т.е. каждый вопрос тестирования это запрос к БД)

Уже делал такой сайт до этого, использовал первый вариант, но с сессиями периодически выходят какие-то ошибки, то сессионная переменная не удалится, то еще что. Если все-таки первый вариант является более правильным, то насколько redis подходит для таких нужд или какое бы хранилище посоветовали бы вы?

Спасибо.

Comment: @z_coder, я вообще не вижу смысла трогать сервер после выбора теста. И 100, и 200 вопросов, можно спокойно сложить в localStorage или sessionStorage.

Comment: > ложить

класть

Comment: @Deonis , небольшая ремарка: Тесты платные. Предвижу, что у людей будут старые браузеры (у нашей ЦА скорее всего) и в связи с этим могут возникнуть проблемы. В данном случае я к локальным хранилищам отношусь с недоверием. Второе ответы платные и если их хранить на клиенте, то теоретически они доступны и без оплаты. Мои опасения оправданы? или паранойя? Спасибо.

Comment: @z_coder, паранойей я бы не назвал, т.к. доля правды есть. Хоть LocalStorage поддерживается и в IE8, но доступ к данным получить можно. Другое дело, а нужно ли хранить ответы вместе с вопросами? Схему вашу я не знаю, но хранить вопрос с вариантами ответов - вполне достаточно. После окончания теста, данные передаются на сервер, где вы их уже поможете обработать, сравнивая с правильными ответами.

В общем, если IE ниже восьмой версии учитывать не нужно и правильные ответы не хранить на клиенте, то не вижу причин, чтоб не рассматривать такой вариант.

Comment: @Deonis , На сайте будет возможность выбирать сразу несколько категорий, а это может быть более 1000 вопросов одновременно (конечно мало кто способен пройти такое количество тестов за раз, но такая возможность будет). Могут ли возникнуть проблемы с локальными хранилищами с таким количеством данных? Спасибо.

Comment: @z_coder, в среднем LocalStorage позволяет хранить около 5Мб данных. Ту уже надо смотреть на ваши объемы и проверять. Попробуйте, например, сохранить эти 1000 вопросов в файл и посмотреть сколько он будет весить.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать key-value хранилище, или же сделать memory табличку в базе, тогда все сведется к проталкиванию данных через локальный сокет, что быстрее локальных сессий.

В случае key-value хранилища главное выбрать правильное формирование key, как вариант x-y-z, где x - id категории, y - id теста, z - id вопроса.

В случае с таблицей в памяти ничего не посоветуешь не зная всею структуру и все возможные варианты данных.

я использовал memcached, мне понравилось, узким местом стал канал, а не мощности сервера

Comment: Я именно про key-value и имел ввиду в качестве первого варианта. В прошлый раз использовал массив, который хранился в сессии. При каждом запросе к серверу гонял пользователя по этому массиву. После прохождения сессия обнулялась. Но не все гладко вышло с сессиями. Поэтому вопрос в том какое еще хранилище можно использовать для временного хранения key-value массива между запросами к серверу. Вы утверждаете, что memcached годен для этих нужд?

Comment: я не знаю на какой объем у вас наберется данных, но если у сервера есть столько оперативной памяти, чтобы вместить все тесты разом, то я бы именно так и сделал.